# Android - Error only on debug

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin

In my Xamarin android app, I deserialize objects from URL using JSON.

I also use mvvmcross and on one of the view models where I retrieve the data through HttpClient, I keep getting the error "WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure".

This only started happening once I moved my app to API level 18.

Here is the code;

> string page = "https://api.github.com/repositories";
>
> ```
>         // ... Use HttpClient.
>         using ( HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
>         {
>             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent",
> ```
>
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
>
> ```
>             using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
>             using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
>             {
>                 // ... Read the string.
>                 string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>
>                 // ... Display the result.
>                 RepoNames = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Repo>>(result);
>             }
>         }
> ```

I gave the Internet permission on the manifest.

I only get this error while debugging, once I deploy my project to a real device, it works perfectly. However, because of this I cannot debug my project.

What could be the reason for it and is there a way to fix it? Because it's a major inconvinence not to be ablo to debug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to use ModernHttpClient http://log.paulbetts.org/fast-http-with-modernhttpclient/ from NuGet. This bug is old one, and i think it's internal

Comment: If the bug only appeared when you started using API level 18, it might be possible you're experiencing the following Android bug.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58230#c35